# ttk.combobox: How to place a default text inside the box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, ttk

Tried using `textvariable` and `insert` but it didn't work. What I hope to achieve is this:[image]

But the text wont be stored as a value inside the combobox just a default text when you haven't selected anything yet.

This is my code so far:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.title('CSSD')
topFrame=Frame(root,width=800,height=150,pady=10,padx=250)
area=Label(topFrame,text='CSSD')
area.config(font=("Courier", 100))
frame=Frame(root,highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=100, height=100, bd= 0)
frame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")
username = Label(frame, text='User Name')
username.config(font='Arial',width=15)
password = Label(frame, text='Password')
password.config(font='Arial',width=15)
enteruser = Entry(frame, textvariable=StringVar(),font=large_font)
enterpass = Entry(frame, show='*', textvariable=StringVar(),font=large_font)


combo=ttk.Combobox(frame)
combo['values']=('Clinic 1','Clinic 2','Clinic 3','Clinic 4','Clinic 5','Clinic 6','Clinic 10','Clinic 11','OB')
combo.state(['readonly'])
combo.grid(row=0,sticky=NW)


topFrame.grid(row=0,sticky=EW)
area.grid(row=0,columnspan=300)
username.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
enteruser.grid(row=1, column=1)
password.grid(row=2, sticky=E)
enterpass.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `set` method like so:

```
combo.set('default')
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. But is it possible for the default text to reappear when I select a value then deselect it?

Comment: @lu_laude It's currently set as "readonly". Is that going to change?

Comment: No, this is ok. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option in case nobody mentioned it.

```py
method = StringVar(value='default') 
choosen = ttk.Combobox(root, width = 14, textvariable = method, )
```

And this is working in `Checkbutton` too.